# Can we edit the EPC of UHF tag to a URL ?

Tags: rfid

Can we set EPC of the UHF tag from E282XXXX..., to some URL link? Like https://www.google.com??
Is this possible?? 
I know that we can edit NFC tag by giving url in the NDEF data with NXP tag writer app. 
I wanted to do the same with UHF tags as well.
UHF tag details: International Standards
 EPC Class 1 Gen 2
 ISO 18000-6CTg EPC Class 1 Gen 2
 ISO 18000-6C
Operating Frequency
860 - 960 MHz
Integrated Circuit (IC)
NXP UCODE G2iL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [NXP UCODE G2iL](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SL3S1203_1213.pdf) you want to use does not have the area (User Memory) necessary to describe the URL.

2.1.1 Memory
 - 128-bit of EPC memory
 - 64-bit Tag IDentifier (TID) including 32-bit factory locked unique serial number
 - 32-bit kill password to permanently disable the tag
 - 32-bit access password to allow a transition into the secured state

If you want to include URL in RFID tag data, please use tag with user memory area.

Since "GS1 EPC Tag Data Standard 1.9", the format of the user memory area is specified, and if you use the AI 8200 you can describe the URL of up to 70 characters.
However, this URL is related to the corresponding product, and should not describe any URL not related to the product.
Let's use AI 91 to AI 99 etc. if you write any URL not related to product.

For example, you can check URL data encoding/decoding on this [EPC User Memory Encoder/Decoder](https://www.gs1us.org/tools/user-memory-encoder-decoder).
If you select "AI 8200 - PRODUCT URL" in "Add a data element" of "Input Data" and enter the URL in the field, the encoded data in hexadecimal is displayed below it.

AI is an acronym for Application Identifier and is specified here [GS1 General Specifications](https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf).